# How to use SQLAlchemy's `one_or_none` query method?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use the `one_or_none` query method to retrieve a record from my database but when I pass in a kwargs like I normally would with the `filter_by` method, it says it doesn't expect that keyword.

I tried going through the [doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.one_or_none), but there's not description of the method's argument or an example.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of what you've tried etc. The docs don't list args since you're not supposed to pass any to `Query.one_or_none()`.

Answer (score 23):

If you do `Product.query.filter_by(id=101).first()`, and there is no product with id 101 in your database, it will return `None`. If you have a product with id 101 on your db, it will return the first database hit as an instance of class `Product`.

You can also do a `Product.query.filter_by(name='apple').one_or_none()`, which will return `None` if there is no product named `apple` in your database, or an instance of class `Product` if there is exactly one product named `apple` in your database, or raises an exception if there are multiple products named `apple` in your database.